# Using >nul in a variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, command, set, nul

Does anyone know how to stop `>nul` being ignored when set in a variable, or is this not possible? I have a feeling that it's one of those things that will only work once all variables have been expanded or something, but it can't hurt to ask.

Example:

```
@echo off

:: Won't work
SET pause_5=ping localhost /n 6 >nul
%pause_5%

:: Will work
SET pause_5=ping localhost /n 6
%pause_5% >nul

exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put quotes around the argument:

```
set "pause_5=ping localhost /n 6 >nul"
```

Another option is to escape characters that will be interpreted by the shell:

```
set pause_5=ping localhost /n 6 ^>nul
```

But usually the quotes approach is a lot easier.

The way you wrote is essentially said »set `pause_5` to `ping localhost /n 6` and ignore the output of the `set` command.«.

Comment: Huh. I didn't know that quotes could cross over onto the variable name. I thought you could only use them around the variable. Cool! Is there any particular downside to escaping the character?

Comment: It's just easier to miss something if there are multiple things to escape. With quotes you're explicitly escaping everything. And as far as `set` is concerned, *everything* is its argument; i.e. the variable, the `=` and the value.