# using > /dev/null when setting a variable

Tags: bash, variables, null, output

So I found this answer and it didn't work for me. Couldn't find anything else.

[Using >nul in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686038/using-nul-in-a-variable)

What I'm trying to do is prevent output when setting a variable like this.

```
var=$(/bin/command.out)
```

If the command doesn't produce an error, then there's no problem. But if it does, it prints it all out to the terminal. I tried adding this, but it just seems to get ignored.

```
var=$(/bin/command.out) > /dev/null
```

I've treid putting everything to the right of the = in quotes. I've tried doing the escape character like that guy suggested. No luck.

Thanks.

just realized that link was for batch. I'm working in bash just so that's clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is likely that the error is being printed to STDERR. There are two "channels" through which something can send a message to the terminal, one is called STDOUT, which is used for most general output, and the other is STDERR which is reserved for errors and warnings. When you write:

```
command > /dev/null
```

You are only telling it to direct STDOUT to /dev/null. STDERR will still go to the terminal. If you want to catch both, you can do something like this:

```
command 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

The number associated with STDERR is 2, STDOUT is 1, so this is saying, redirect all the messages on channel 1 to /dev/null and also do the same for all messages on channel 2. Usually the 1 is implied, i.e. when you just put `>` it is automatically redirecting STDOUT.

So in your example you would want something like this:

```
var=$(/bin/command.out 2> /dev/null)
```

This way if your command barfs, the barf wont be seen, and var will just be empty. Which I think is what you want

Answer (score 5):

You need

```
var=$(/bin/command.out 2> /dev/null)
```

E.g.

```sh
$ var=$(not_a_command  2> /dev/null)
$ echo $var

$(uname  2> /dev/null)
$ echo $var
Linux
```

---

There are two outputs in Linux:

- `1>` (commonly called *STDOUT*) which is the output
- `2>` (called *STDERR*) which is the error output.

It was the error output which was writing the message.

You can find more details from the following chapter of the "*Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide*":
[*Chapter 20*. **I/O Redirection**](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)